# Dependency is not satisfiable: libre2-4(>=20160901)

Tags: dependencies, chromium

I'm trying to install ungoogled chromium using .deb file using [this](https://software.opensuse.org/download/package?package=ungoogled-chromium&project=home:ungoogled_chromium) site for linux mint(ubuntu bionic), however i get the error in the title, same error when i'm using manual installation option
I tried different thing and none of them worked:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`:

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

`sudo apt update --fix-missing:`

```
All packages are up to date.
```

`sudo apt install -f`:

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

`sudo apt-get install libre2-4`:

```
E: Package 'libre2-4' has no installation candidate
```

Synaptic package manager: Tag "Custom Filters > Broken" is empty, Searching "libre2-4" yields no results, the closest results are "libre0" "libre2-5" "libre2-dev". It shows "libre2-5" and "libre2-dev" as installed

packages.debian.org: no package named libre2-4, however there are libre2-3 and libre2-5

I also used some script that lets me change "libre2-4 (>=20160901)" to "libre2-5" inside the .deb file "Depends:". It got installed but crashed on start

Comment: Don't F with the `.deb`! Did you try installing `libre2-5`?

Comment: Yes, I still get the same error. I forgot to add but while installing manually it says: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. Although i think it's the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package exists in Ubuntu bionic:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libs/libre2-4

You may try to install it manually, but there is something broken on your system

Comment: Thank you, it worked.